# Video in google meet

Tags: video-player

Unable to open my video in google meet
Voice is clear in google meet conference, but video cannot be switched on
I use Ubuntu and firefox browser

when I followed instructions for Cheese,I am able to see myself in the video camera
webcam from logitech is working. But in google meet, video could not be turned on

Comment: You haven't provided release details, nor if your `firefox` is the default for your *unstated* Ubuntu release, or you've switched to a different version (snap or other).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my camera worked fine in cheese, but if I tried to use it in meet, it would say "camera starting" and the progress bar would stick at about 90%. The microphone on the camera worked fine.

Searching for a solution didn't help, I just found hundreds of different articles telling me how to set the permissions, which were already correct.

By playing around with any settings I could find, I discovered that if I turned off background blurring the camera started correctly. I could then turn background blurring back on, and it stayed working.